# how to reject emails with specific subject on Mail server postfix spamassassin?

Tags: postfix, spam, spamassassin

I have postfix and spamassassin. recently I found an email with subject "XXX" to all company email addresses and aliases.

So I was wondering if I can reject sending emails with specific subject "XXX" to the company @domain.com.

please explain as I'm not advanced :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you need to specifically reject them or can you just treat them as Spam?

Answer (score 3):

```
header  __AR_SUBJECT_XXX           Subject =~ /XXX/
header  __AR_TO_DOMAIN_COM         ToCc:addr =~ /\@domain\.com$/i
meta    AR_SUBJ_XXX_TO_DOMAIN_COM  __AR_SUBJECT_XXX && __AR_TO_DOMAIN_COM
score   AR_SUBJ_XXX_TO_DOMAIN_COM  5.0
```

You'll have to create a perl regular expression matching that subject. If it's literally "XXX" then what I have above will work. If you just want a literal string match and don't want to deal with regular expressions, surround that literal string with `\Q` and `\E`, like `/\QXXX\E/` (or, for case-insensitive, `/\QXXX\E/i`). You'll still want to escape your slashes though.

This creates two predicate rules, one to match the subject and one to match either `To` or `Cc` (using a special pseudo-header designed for that purpose) on its address (using a special modifier to restrict the field to just the address) that matches the given domain. Don't forget to escape your at signs (`@` as `\@`) and dots (`.` as `\.`). The `$` anchors against the end of the address so you don't match `joe@domain.com.br`

The predicate rules are combined by the `meta` rule that requires both to fire, and when that happens, it will add 5.0 points to the message's spam score (by default, SpamAssassin uses a spam threshold of 5).

This is a broad rule and it seems a bit risky to me, but it literally implements your request. You're definitely better off ensuring that you have [DNSBLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNSBL) and [Bayes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_spam_filtering) enabled and functioning properly before you start tinkering with custom rules, as those are the two primary workhorses of SpamAssassin.

Learn more about configuring:

- [DNSBLs in SpamAssassin](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SPAMASSASSIN/DnsBlocklists) (both for IPs and for URIs)
- [Bayes in SpamAssassin](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SPAMASSASSIN/BayesInSpamAssassin) (this requires active training)
- [Writing rules in SpamAssassin](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SPAMASSASSIN/WritingRules)